# Hybrid Radeon/Intel on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics, radeon

I am the owner of HP Pavilion G7 with a hybrid Intel HD3000 graphics card and ATI Radeon 6730M.

Every time you try to install the Radeon drivers, the system runs in "low graphics mode". The equipment is constantly working on the graphics card from Intel, the power supply is wasted disputes, which I wanted to use in games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days, perhaps even weeks, I was able to run the graphics card from AMD, and while the hybrid mechanism.

I worked on Ubuntu 14.04.1 using the latest drivers from your video card manufacturer.

1. Download the drivers from AMD / ATI.
2. Run it in the console (in graphical mode) by typing `sudo sh ./amd.run` (I've simplified the long file name).
3. Select the option to install the driver (the second option, the first is to create files for your Linux distribution).
4. Select auto mode
5. After installation of driver will be asked to restart your computer - do not do it.
6. In the console, type `sudo aticonfig --initial -f`
7. Restart the computer

Optional: When the computer does not start using a more powerful graphics card, you can manually run:

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

Strange errors? The computer detects that I am using the ATI Radeon HD7400, HD6370 when I have, but this is just a small detail not affecting the operation of the equipment.